Correct message to notify users about errors in data
I'm working on a map software project and I'm not quite sure how to write a legend entry.
On the map we display various sections consisting of multiple segments. If a segment contains some incorrect data we should display the section in a different manner.
Question is, what's the correct legend message to notify users that section contains one or more segments with incorrect data?

Section with segments errors
Section with segments' errors
Section with errors on segments
Section with errors in segments

As a non-native speaker I lack the gut feeling and I can't honestly tell, which one is correct (they all seem correct to me) or best to use.

You can simply say "Segment error" or "Segment error in section {X}" if you can refer to the section by its name or identifier in a helpful way.

There may be more than one erroneous segment.

What’s a section? Is it a rectangular region bounded by northern and southern latitudinal limits and eastern and western longitudinal limits? What’s the nature of the possible errors? Who are your typical users? How much can they be expected to know about the sections and the data? How well are they likely to understand 5he nature of the possible errors in the data?

I like Hic Sunt Dragones, no?

I think you’ll want dracones, @DJohnson, no?

@PaulTanenbaum - even though those are valid question, they are not to be answered in the legend. The text I wanted to check is in the map legend. There is a dotted line with "Segment error" label. All other information are available elsewhere. This is just to explain why there's suddenly a different line on the map

I’m not suggesting that all that info belongs in the legend. But it is all contextual detail that is relevant to the effective design of your graphic, including the crafting of textual labels.

@PaulTanenbaum Right you are.

Simply showing "Segment error(s)" is your best bet. It's succinct and applies to a single error in that section or to multiple errors.

This is correct. In the cited context, segment is a "noun adjunct" (noun being used adjectivally). Noun adjuncts are nearly always singular, whether it's one car radio or two car radios.
